# How do I set icons in the top panel with arbitrary spacing, as was possible in 10.10?

Tags: 12.04, panel

Just installed 12.04 on a laptop; I still have 10.10 on a server so I can compare directly and not just rely on my memory.  Generally 12.10 is ok but the UI has taken a major step downhill.

I have reverted to gnome classic which goes most of the way to the old look and feel but the icons will not stay where I put them. They either go to the left or the right or the centre but I want them where I put them, so that I get reasonable spacing.

I have had a look at the settings via dconf-editor: I looked for something like 'snap-to-alignment' or the like but found nothing. I have a bad feeling that this may be some new feature of the underlying UI widget, i.e. in the source, rather than a configurable value.

The answer from here: [How can I evenly space icons in the panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5288/how-can-i-evenly-space-icons-in-the-panel) is to use Active Window Navigator and stop fighting with the current panel.

Is that the best I can do?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/130011/how-to-permute-various-icons-in-indicator-applet

Comment: ... or Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/69576/how-to-customize-the-gnome-classic-panel  ?

Comment: I had seen the second possible dupe already. It says this  "Note that the panel items snap to the left/center/right of the panel, so they might need to be dragged some distance before they move at all." So that is for sure my problem, the icons snap as stated. I'd like to know how to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this page and some more googling gave me the answer: [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)  That is, the options are a) work with Unity b) use the option for 'classic gnome' in gnome 3, which has some small differences from the gnome 2 panel such as the one I asked about above c) downgrade to, say, 10.10.  Thanks for the responses.